# Internet Explorer 11 Chart using random values to update

Tags: vue.js, chart.js, internet-explorer-11

The project is built with vue.js. The charts work fine in all browsers, except for IE11 (not tested in IE10 or below).

Here's the chart (chart.js):

```
 var dia_btc_values_2 = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < all_months_2.length; i++) {
    dia_btc_values_2.push(rnd(calc('btc_value_up', all_months_2[i])));

    var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart2").getContext('2d');
      var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
          labels: ["Start", "100 Tage", "1000 Tage", "2000 Tage"],
          datasets: [{
            label: '#',
            data: dia_btc_values_2,
            backgroundColor: [
              'rgba(69, 153, 231, 0.27)'
            ],
            borderColor: [
              'rgba(69, 153, 231, 1)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 3
          }]
        },
        options: {
          tooltips: {
              enabled: true,
              mode: 'single',
              callbacks: {
                  label: function(tooltipItems, data) {
                      return tooltipItems.yLabel + ' €';
                  }
              }
          },
          maintainAspectRatio: false,
          animation:{
            duration: 0
          },
          legend: {
            display: false
          },
          scales: {
            yAxes: [{
              ticks: {
                beginAtZero:true
              }
            }]
          }
        }
      });
      }
```

The chart should take values from this input field:

```
<input type="range" min="1" max="5" step="1" v-model="szenario" id="szenario_range" v-on:change="up_szenario" v-on:input="up_szenario">
```

and that's the method up_szenario:

```
up_szenario: function() {
  var vm = this;
  switch (vm.szenario) {
    case '1':
      szenario = 7;
      vm.szenario_conv = 7;
      vm.hold_strategy = 12.5;
      break;
    case '2':
      szenario = 6;
      vm.szenario_conv = 6;
      vm.hold_strategy = 9;
      break;
    case '3':
      szenario = 5;
      vm.szenario_conv = 5;
      vm.hold_strategy = 7.5;
      break;
    case '4':
      szenario = 3;
      vm.szenario_conv = 3;
      vm.hold_strategy = 5.5;
      break;
    case '5':
      szenario = 1;
      vm.szenario_conv = 1;
      vm.hold_strategy = 1.8;
      break;
    default:
      vm.szenario_conv = 5;
      vm.hold_strategy = 7.5;
  }
}
```

What you get when you try around in IE11 - the value of szenario is totally random, for example when szenario is 1, it should be 7 due the method up_szenario, but it is a random number between 1 and 7 and therefor showing the wrong graph/chart.

Is there anything I am missing? Do you need more information?
Thanks

Edit: for better understanding: Changing the input should also change the value of szenario as in the method 'up_szenario' defined. But all IE11 does, it changes the szenario value, but not as declared, it changes it randomly between 1, 3, 5 and 7.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution for anyone interested: There's a function which creates the charts, once the input range field changes its value. Wrapping it with a setTimeout function solved the issue. It seems like IE11 had problems with instant execution of the createChart function.

```
szenario_range_input.onchange = function() {    
    setTimeout(function() {     
        $('#myChart').remove();
        $('#myChart2').remove();
        $('.chart-mining-results').append('<canvas id="myChart" width="" height="128px"></canvas>');
        $('.chart-development').append('<canvas id="myChart2" width="" height="128px"></canvas>');
        charts();
    }, 150);    
  }
```